# Efficient method to Update using JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jpa, jersey

I am working on a JPA/Jersey web app and want to know if there is a better way to update a record. Currently, I am doing:

```
@PUT
@Path("update/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response createDevice(
        @PathParam("id") int id,
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("type") int type
        /*MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams*/
        ) {
    try {
        Devices newDevice = entityManager.find(Devices.class, id);
        if(name==null){name=newDevice.getName();}
        if(type != newDevice.getType()){newDevice.setType(type);}
        newDevice.setName(name);
        //newDevice.setType(type);
        entityManager.merge(newDevice);
        return Response.status(201).entity(new ResponseObject("success")).build();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

This works, but if my Devices table had more fields, I would have to check for equality of ALL fields with the values on the original object to see if they've changed, so that my

```
entityManager.merge(newDevice);
```

will only change the values passed in.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you check for equality in the first place? It's useless. Just assign the new value. Also, if you're not opening the entityManager, why are you closing it? And what's the point of calling merge()?

Comment: The entity manager needs to merge the newDevice with the one in JPA with the same id, right? Also to call entityManager.merge, I think entityManager is opened. I also don't see where I'm checking for equality...